# I get following PYBIND11_MODULE error: "no instance of function template "pybind11::module_::def" matches the argument list"

Tags: c++, cmake, pybind11

I cloned this: https://github.com/dickreuter/PokerEquityCalculator Github Repo and rewrote it so it would work for ranges too. The entire code doesn't seem to have any issues (as VS Code doesn't highlite it red). The only thing it does highlite red is the following code:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(Scoring, m) {
    m.def("montecarlo", &montecarlo);
}
```

Specifically the .def() thing. I am knew to C++ and this is my first time using pybind11 so I don't have a clue what it means. When compiling the code with cmake it compiles just fine, BUT it doesn't create a pyd nor dll file, which I belive is caused by this mistake.

Scoring.cpp (where the error is):

```
//cppimport

/*
<%
setup_pybind11(cfg)
%>
*/

#include "Scoring.h"

#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/complex.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <pybind11/chrono.h>


namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace pybind11::literals;


PYBIND11_MODULE(Scoring, m) {
    m.def("montecarlo", &montecarlo);
}


namespace
{
    constexpr auto x = std::array<int, 4>{2, 2, 2, 1};
}

bool eval_best_hand(const std::vector<std::set<std::string>>& all_cards_with_table_combined)
// returns true if first player has best hand
{
    std::vector<std::tuple< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>, std::string>> all_players_score;
    std::vector<std::tuple< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>, std::string>>  all_players_score_original;
    bool best_hand;

    for (const auto& cards_with_table : all_cards_with_table_combined)
    {
        auto result = calc_score(cards_with_table);
        all_players_score.emplace_back(result);
    }
    all_players_score_original = all_players_score;

    std::sort(all_players_score.begin(), all_players_score.end(), std::greater<>());
    if (all_players_score[0] == all_players_score_original[0])
        best_hand = true; // first player is best hand
    else
        best_hand = false; // different player is best hand

    return best_hand;
}

Score get_rcounts(const std::set<std::string>& all_cards_with_table_combined,
    std::vector<std::size_t> available_ranks,
    const std::string original_ranks) {
    Score rcounts;
    for (const auto& card : all_cards_with_table_combined) {
        available_ranks.emplace_back(original_ranks.find(card.substr(0, 1)));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        int count = std::count(available_ranks.begin(), available_ranks.end(), i);
        if (count > 0) {
            rcounts.emplace_back(std::make_pair(count, i));
        }
    }
    return rcounts;
}

std::tuple< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>, std::string> calc_score(const std::set<std::string>& all_cards_with_table_combined) {
    const std::string original_ranks = "23456789TJQKA";
    const std::vector<std::string> original_suits{ "C","D","H","S" };
    std::vector<std::size_t> available_ranks;
    std::vector<std::string> available_suits;
    std::vector<int> score;
    std::vector<int> card_ranks;
    std::vector<int> sorted_card_ranks;
    std::string hand_type;
    bool flush = false;
    bool straight = false;

    Score rcounts;
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, std::string>> rsuits;

    rcounts = get_rcounts(all_cards_with_table_combined, available_ranks, original_ranks);

    // sort tuple and split into score and card ranks
    std::sort(rcounts.begin(), rcounts.end(), std::greater<std::tuple<int, int>>());
    for (auto it = std::make_move_iterator(rcounts.begin()),
        end = std::make_move_iterator(rcounts.end()); it != end; ++it)
    {
        score.push_back(std::get<0>(*it));  // amount of occurrences
        card_ranks.push_back(std::get<1>(*it));  // ranks of individual cards
    }

    bool potential_threeofakind = score[0] == 3;
    bool potential_twopair = score == std::vector<int> {2, 2, 1, 1, 1};
    bool potential_pair = score == std::vector<int> {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

    auto sub_score2 = slice(score, 0, 2);
    auto sub_score4 = slice(score, 0, 5);
    auto sub_score0 = slice(score, 0, 0);
    // # fullhouse(three of a kind and pair, or two three of a kind)
    if (sub_score2 == std::vector<int> {3, 2} || sub_score2 == std::vector<int> {3, 3}) {
        // make adjustment
        card_ranks = slice(card_ranks, 0, 2);
        score = { 3,2 };
    }
    // edge case: convert three pair to two pair
    //const auto x = &score[3];
    else if (sub_score4 == std::vector<int>{2, 2, 2, 1}) {
        score = { 2,2,1 };
        int kicker = std::max(card_ranks[2], card_ranks[3]);
        card_ranks = { card_ranks[0], card_ranks[1], kicker };
    }
    else if (score[0] == 4) {  // four of a kind
        score = { 4, };
        // avoid for example 11, 8, 9
        sorted_card_ranks = card_ranks;
        std::sort(sorted_card_ranks.begin(), sorted_card_ranks.end(), std::greater <>());
        card_ranks = { sorted_card_ranks[0], sorted_card_ranks[1] };
    }
    else if (score.size() >= 5) {  // high card, flush, straight and straight flush
        // straight
        // adjust for 5 high straight
        if (std::find(card_ranks.begin(), card_ranks.end(), 12) != card_ranks.end())
            card_ranks.push_back(-1);
        sorted_card_ranks = card_ranks;
        std::sort(sorted_card_ranks.begin(), sorted_card_ranks.end(), std::greater <>());  // sort again

        for (int i = 0; i < sorted_card_ranks.size() - 4; ++i) {
            straight = sorted_card_ranks[i] - sorted_card_ranks[i + 4] == 4;
            if (straight == true) {
                card_ranks = {
                    sorted_card_ranks[i], sorted_card_ranks[i + 1], sorted_card_ranks[i + 2], sorted_card_ranks[i + 3],
                    sorted_card_ranks[i + 4] };
                break;
            }
        }

        //flush
        for (std::string card : all_cards_with_table_combined) {
            available_suits.emplace_back(card.substr(1, 1));
        }

        std::vector<int> suit_counts;
        std::vector<std::string> suit_cards;
        for (const auto& suit : original_suits) {  // why can original_suits not be a string and suit a char?
            int count = std::count(available_suits.begin(), available_suits.end(), suit);
            if (count > 0) {
                rsuits.emplace_back(std::make_pair(count, suit));
            }
        }
        std::sort(rsuits.begin(), rsuits.end(), std::greater<std::tuple<int, std::string>>());
        flush = std::get<0>(rsuits[0]) >= 5; // the most occurred suit appear at least 5 times

        if (flush == true)
        {
            auto flush_suit = std::get<1>(rsuits[0]);
            std::set<std::string> flush_hand;
            for (auto card : all_cards_with_table_combined) {
                if (card[1] == flush_suit[0]) {
                    flush_hand.insert(card);
                }
            }

            Score rcounts_flush = get_rcounts(flush_hand, available_ranks, original_ranks);
            // sort tuple and split into score and card ranks
            std::sort(rcounts_flush.begin(), rcounts_flush.end(), std::greater<std::tuple<int, int>>());
            card_ranks.clear();
            score.clear();
            for (auto it = std::make_move_iterator(rcounts_flush.begin()),
                end = std::make_move_iterator(rcounts_flush.end()); it != end; ++it)
            {
                score.push_back(std::get<0>(*it));  // ranks of individual cards
                card_ranks.push_back(std::get<1>(*it));  // amount of occurrences
            }

            //  # check for straight in flush
            // if 12 in card_ranks and -1 not in card_ranks : # adjust if 5 high straight
            if (std::find(card_ranks.begin(), card_ranks.end(), 12) != card_ranks.end() &&
                !(std::find(card_ranks.begin(), card_ranks.end(), -1) != card_ranks.end())) {
                card_ranks.push_back(-1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < card_ranks.size() - 4; i++) {
                straight = card_ranks[i] - card_ranks[i + 4] == 4;
                if (straight == true)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // no pair, straight, flush, or straight flush
        if (flush == false && straight == false)
            score = { 1 };
        else if (flush == false && straight == true)
            score = { 3, 1, 2 };
        else if (flush == true && straight == false)
            score = { 3, 1, 3 };
        else if (flush == true && straight == true)
            score = { 5 };
    }
    if (score[0] == 1 && potential_threeofakind == true)
        score = { 3,1 };
    else if (score[0] == 1 && potential_twopair == true)
        score = { 2, 2, 1 };
    else if (score[0] == 1 && potential_pair == true)
        score = { 2, 1, 1 };

    if (score[0] == 5)
        // # crdRanks=crdRanks[:5] # five card rule makes no difference {:5] would be incorrect
        hand_type = "StraightFlush";
    else if (score[0] == 4)
        hand_type = "FoufOfAKind"; // crdRanks = crdRanks[:2] # already implemented above
    else if (slice(score, 0, 2) == std::vector<int> {3, 2})
        hand_type = "FullHouse"; // # crdRanks = crdRanks[:2] # already implmeneted above
    else if (slice(score, 0, 3) == std::vector<int> {3, 1, 3}) {
        hand_type = "Flush";
        card_ranks = slice(card_ranks, 0, 5);
    }

    else if (slice(score, 0, 3) == std::vector<int> {3, 1, 2}) {
        hand_type = "Straight";
        card_ranks = slice(card_ranks, 0, 5);
    }

    else if (slice(score, 0, 2) == std::vector<int> {3, 1}) {
        hand_type = "ThreeOfAKind";
        card_ranks = slice(card_ranks, 0, 3);
    }
    else if (slice(score, 0, 2) == std::vector<int> {3, 1}) {
        hand_type = "ThreeOfAKind";
        card_ranks = slice(card_ranks, 0, 3);
    }
    else if (slice(score, 0, 2) == std::vector<int> {2, 2}) {
        hand_type = "TwoPair";
        card_ranks = slice(card_ranks, 0, 3);
    }
    else if (score[0] == 2) {
        hand_type = "Pair";
        card_ranks = slice(card_ranks, 0, 4);
    }
    else if (score[0] == 1) {
        hand_type = "HighCard";
        card_ranks = slice(card_ranks, 0, 5);
    }
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("Card Type error!");

    auto res = std::make_tuple(score, card_ranks, hand_type);
    return res;
}


double montecarlo(const std::set<std::string>& my_cards, const std::set<std::string>& cards_on_table, const std::vector<std::vector<std::set<std::string>>> ranges, const int number_of_players, const int iterations) { 

    int wins = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        Deck deck;
        /*
        std::vector<int> idx_list;
        for (int i=0; i < ranges.size(); i++){
            idx_list.push_back(rand() % ranges[i].size());

        }      

        std::set<std::string> opponents_hole;
        for (auto i=0; i<ranges.size(); i++){
            for (auto it = ranges[i].begin(); it!=ranges[i].end(); it++){
        
            //auto it = next(ranges[i].begin(), idx_list[i]);   this was a mistake as this just gives us the card of the set and not the entire set
            //auto card_string = *it;
           //     opponents_hole.push_back(card_string);
            

            std::string choosen_opponent_pair = ranges[i][idx_list[i]];
            opponents_hole.insert(std::string(1, choosen_opponent_pair));
            } 
        }
    */       

     std::vector<int> idx_list;
     for (int i=0; i < ranges.size(); i++){
        std::random_device random_device;
        std::mt19937 engine{random_device()};
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, ranges[i].size() - 1);
        int k = dist(engine);
        idx_list.push_back(k);
      }
 
 /*
 22     std::set<std::string> opponents_hole;
 23     for (auto it = ranges[0][0].begin(); it != ranges[0][0].end(); ++it){
 24         std::string k = *it;
 25         std::cout << k;
 26         //std::string choosen_opponent_pair = ranges[i][idx_list[i]];
 27         //opponents_hole.insert(std::string(1, choosen_opponent_pair));
 28     }
 29     */

     std::vector<std::set<std::string>> opponents_hole;
     std::set<std::string> cards;
     for (int i=0; i<ranges.size(); i++){
         for (auto it = ranges[i][idx_list[i]].begin(); it!=ranges[i][idx_list[i]].end(); it++){
             //std::string choosen_opponent_pair = ranges[i][idx_list[i]];
            //opponents_hole.insert(std::string(1, choosen_opponent_pair));
             std::string k = *it;
             std::cout << k;
             cards.insert(k);
             if(cards.size()==2){
                 opponents_hole.push_back(cards);
                 cards.clear();
             }
             //opponents_hole.insert(cards);

         }

     }
        
        deck.remove_visible_cards(my_cards, cards_on_table);
        deck.distribute_cards(number_of_players, opponents_hole);
        std::vector<std::set<std::string>> cards_with_table_combined = deck.get_cards_combined();
        bool first_player_has_best_hand = eval_best_hand(cards_with_table_combined);
        if (first_player_has_best_hand == true)
            wins += 1;
    }
    double equity = (wins / (double)iterations) * 100.0;
    std::cout << "Equity: " << equity << "%" << std::endl;
    return equity;
}



Deck::Deck() {
    std::string combined;
    //std::cout << "Constructing deck..." << std::endl;
    for (char& r : ranks) {
        for (char& s : suits) {
            combined = std::string() + r + s;
            full_deck.insert(combined);
        };
    };
    //std::cout << "Cards in deck: " << full_deck.size() << std::endl;
}

void Deck::remove_visible_cards(const Hand& my_cards_, const std::set<std::string>& cards_on_table_) {
    // remove my_cards and cards_on_table from full_deck
    set_difference(full_deck.begin(), full_deck.end(), my_cards_.begin(), my_cards_.end(),
        std::inserter(remaining_cards_tmp, remaining_cards_tmp.end()));

    // remove visible table cards from deck
    set_difference(remaining_cards_tmp.begin(), remaining_cards_tmp.end(), cards_on_table_.begin(),
        cards_on_table_.end(),
        std::inserter(remaining_cards, remaining_cards.end()));

    //std::cout << "Remaining cards: " << remaining_cards.size() << std::endl;

    this->my_cards = my_cards_.cards;
    this->cards_on_table = cards_on_table_;

    //std::cout << "Removed my cards from deck...\n";
}

void Deck::distribute_cards(int number_players, const std::vector<std::set<std::string>>& opponents_hole) {  //number_players INLCUDING OURSELF
    constexpr size_t cards_in_hand = 2;

    std::vector<std::string> shuffled_deck(remaining_cards.begin(), remaining_cards.end());
    std::shuffle(shuffled_deck.begin(), shuffled_deck.end(), std::mt19937_64(std::random_device()()));
    std::vector<Hand> player_hands(number_players);  // empty container

    auto hand_it = player_hands.begin();
    *hand_it = Hand(my_cards);  // set my own cards
    hand_it++;

    auto card_it = shuffled_deck.begin();
    int i = 0;
    while (hand_it != player_hands.end() && i<opponents_hole.size()) {
        //*hand_it = Hand(std::set<std::string>{*++card_it, * ++card_it});
        //auto it = next(opponents_hole.begin(), i);
        //std::set<std::string>::iterator it = opponents_hole.begin();
        //std::advance(it, i);
        //*hand_it = Hand(*it);
        //++hand_it;
        //i++;
        *hand_it = Hand(opponents_hole[i]);
        i++;
    }

    i=0;

    while (cards_on_table.size() < 5) {
        cards_on_table.emplace(*++card_it);
    }

    // print out the hands
    //for (auto const& player_hand : player_hands) {
    //  std::cout << "Cards: ";
    //  for (const auto& card : player_hand.cards)
    //      std::cout << card << " ";
    //  std::cout << std::endl;
    //}
    this->player_hands = player_hands;

    //std::cout << "Cards on table: ";
    //print_set(cards_on_table);
}

std::vector<std::set<std::string>> Deck::get_cards_combined() {
    std::set<std::string> cards_with_table_combined;
    std::vector<std::set<std::string>> all_cards_with_table_combined;

    for (const auto& player_hand : player_hands) {
        cards_with_table_combined = player_hand.cards;
        cards_with_table_combined.insert(cards_on_table.begin(), cards_on_table.end());
        all_cards_with_table_combined.push_back(cards_with_table_combined);
    }

    return all_cards_with_table_combined;
}

void Deck::print_set(const std::set<std::string>& set) {
    for (const auto& card : set)
        std::cout << card << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.27.1)

project (equity_calculator)
enable_language(C)
enable_language(CXX)

set(pybind11_DIR C:/Python39/Lib/site-packages/pybind11/share/cmake/pybind11)
set(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE C:/Python39/python.exe)
set(pybind11_LIBRARIES C:/Python39/libs/python39.lib)
find_package(pybind11 CONFIG REQUIRED)
include_directories(${pybind11_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message([MAIN] "Found pybind11 v${pybind11_VERSION}: ${pybind11_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

MESSAGE( [Main] " pybind11_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${pybind11_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
MESSAGE( [Main] " pybind11_LIBRARIES = ${pybind11_LIBRARIES}")

#
#   # Create an extension module
#   add_library(mylib MODULE main.cpp)
#   target_link_libraries(mylib pybind11::module)
#
#   # Or embed the Python interpreter into an executable
#   add_executable(myexe main.cpp)
#   target_link_libraries(myexe pybind11::embed)

# method (1): generate `examplelib.pyd`
pybind11_add_module(Scoring Scoring.cpp)

# method (2): generate `examplelib.dll` rename to `examplelib.pyd`
#add_library(Scoring MODULE Scoring.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(Scoring pybind11::module)

MESSAGE( [Main] " pybind11_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${pybind11_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
MESSAGE( [Main] " pybind11_LIBRARIES = ${pybind11_LIBRARIES}")

#add_executable(cpp_use_python cpp_use_python.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(cpp_use_python PRIVATE pybind11::embed)
```

I tried maybe putting the PYBIND11_MODULE at the end, but it still woudln't work. Like I said, I have never used Pybind11 so I don't have any clue what the error means or why cmake doesn't create a pyd file. I also looked at the official Pybind11 documentation, specifically the first steps page, and they did it exactly like that, so I don't get what's wrong.

I would appreciate any help! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you add the whole error message you get & the pybind version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved my problem, by changing a line a haven't previously seen in the Scoring.h file and now I am using cppimport to use my montecarlo function and everything works just fine. Though, when I compile it using cmake it still doesn't create a pyd or dll file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).